# How to display the ID in mysql

Tags: mysql

So I have a table with id and name.
And I have a where condition with

```
name = 'John'
name = 'Ariel'
name = 'Ariel'
name = 'Mary'
name = 'Mary'
```

I want to display it's ID. So the output should be something like this:

```
id  name
1   John 
1   John
3   Ariel
3   Ariel
5   Mary
5   Mary
```

What I did was like this:

```
select id, name from users where
name = 'John' OR
name = 'John' OR
name = 'Ariel' OR
name = 'Ariel' OR
name = 'Mary' OR
name = 'Mary';
```

Also tried the

```
where name in ('John','John','Ariel','Ariel','Mary','Mary');
```

But it will always output like this:

```
id  name
1   John
3   Ariel
5   Mary
```

So how do I display the id even if the condition is duplicate?
I really want to show something like this:

```
id  name
1   John 
1   John
3   Ariel
3   Ariel
5   Mary
5   Mary
```

Or is this even possible?

Note: I have no duplicate records.

Comment: do you have duplicate records in your table?

Comment: nope I don't have

Comment: that's why it is not showing

Comment: Yup, but is it possible even if no duplicate records?

Comment: The query and data you have shown us will NOT give the output you have shown us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a inner join on suqyery for based on union all

```
select m.id, m.name 
from my_table  m 
inner join (
select 'John' as name  from dual 
union all 
select 'John' from dual 
union all 
select 'Ariel' from dual 
union all 
select 'Ariel' from dual 
union all 
select 'Mary' from dual 
union all 
select 'Mary' from dual 
) t on t.name =m.name
```

Comment: Ok I'll try it. Thank you very much.

Comment: It got sql error from this line "select 'John' as name  from dual "